# £ and € error XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding

we are having an error, when trying to view a formatted xml applying a xslt template.

The xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="HandOffForms.xslt"?><form xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  <requestor>ab000186</requestor> <depositList><deposit> <siteReference><![CDATA[1]]></siteReference> <postOffice><![CDATA[1]]></postOffice><tcRef><![CDATA[£]]></tcRef><depositDate>12/12/1212</depositDate><depositValue>1.00</depositValue></deposit></depositList></form>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1" width="720px">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="background-color:#E8E8E8;height:21px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #fff;margin:0;font-family:verdana;font-size: 11px;text-align:left;">Additional Information</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Attribute</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Value</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="form/*">

                    <xsl:variable name="nodoNombre" select="local-name()"></xsl:variable>

                    <xsl:if test="$nodoNombre!='depositList' and $nodoNombre!='chequeList' and $nodoNombre!='bagList'">
                    <tr>
                            <xsl:variable name="css-estilo">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#F1F1F1</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#FFFFFF</xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'requestor'">Requestor</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'queryType'">Query Type</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'channel'">Channel</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'siteReference'">Site Reference</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'siteReference' or local-name() = 'siteRef'">Site Reference</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'depositDate'">Deposit Date</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'depositValue'">Deposit Value</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'sitePost'">Site Post</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'deliveryProof'">Delivery Proof</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'discrepancyValue'">Discrepancy Value</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'discrepancyDate'">Discrepancy Date</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'valOrderPlaced'">Value Order Placed</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'orderRefNumber'">Order Reference Number</xsl:when>  
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'valOrderReceived'">Value Order Received</xsl:when>  
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'G4S_site'">G4S site</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'payeeHolding'">Payee Holding</xsl:when> 
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'contactName'">Contact Name</xsl:when>   
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'contactPhoneNum'">Contact Phone Number</xsl:when>                   
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'carrier'">Carrier</xsl:when>        
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'cageSealNumber'">Cage Seal Number</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                        </td>
                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'discrepancyDate'">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="reformatDateTimeUKtoDate">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="."/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'valOrderPlaced'">
                                    &#163; <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'valOrderReceived'">
                                    &#163; <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'depositValue'">
                                    &#163; <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'discrepancyValue'">
                                    &#163; <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'payeeHolding'">
                                    <xsl:call-template name="formatAcc">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="requestor" select="."/>
                                    </xsl:call-template>

                                </xsl:when>                                         
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="$nodoNombre='depositList'">

                    <table border="1" width="720px">
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>                   
                    <tr>
                        <!--<th colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;background-color:#C0C0C0"><b>Additional Information</b></th>-->
                        <th colspan="5" style="background-color:#E8E8E8;height:21px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #fff;margin:0;font-family:verdana;font-size: 11px;text-align:left;">Deposit List</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Site Reference</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Post Office</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">TC Reference</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Deposit Date</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Deposit Value</th>
                    </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="/form/depositList/deposit">
                            <tr>
                            <xsl:variable name="css-estilo">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#F1F1F1</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#FFFFFF</xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:variable>
                        <td style="{$css-estilo}">

                                <xsl:value-of select="./siteReference"/>
                        </td>
                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./postOffice"/>
                            </td>

                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="./tcRef"/>
                            </td>


                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                            <xsl:call-template name="reformatDateTimeUKtoDate">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="./depositDate"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                            </td>


                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                                &#163; <xsl:value-of select="./depositValue"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </table>
                    </xsl:if>


                    <xsl:if test="$nodoNombre='chequeList'">

                    <table border="1" width="720px">
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<th colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;background-color:#C0C0C0"><b>Additional Information</b></th>-->
                        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:#E8E8E8;height:21px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #fff;margin:0;font-family:verdana;font-size: 11px;text-align:left;">Cheque List</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Cheque Number</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Cheque Value</th>
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:center;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Cheque Date</th>
                    </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="/form/chequeList/cheque">
                            <tr>
                            <xsl:variable name="css-estilo">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#F1F1F1</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#FFFFFF</xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:variable>
                        <td style="{$css-estilo}">

                                <xsl:value-of select="./chequeNumber"/>
                        </td>
                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                                &#163; <xsl:value-of select="./chequeVal"/>
                            </td>

                            <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                                <xsl:call-template name="reformatDateTimeUKtoDate">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="dateTime" select="./chequeDate"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </table>
                    </xsl:if>

                    <xsl:if test="$nodoNombre='bagList'">

                    <table border="1" width="720px">
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <tr>
                        <!--<th colspan="2" style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;background-color:#C0C0C0"><b>Additional Information</b></th>-->
                        <th colspan="3" style="background-color:#E8E8E8;height:21px;border:0;border-top:1px solid #fff;margin:0;font-family:verdana;font-size: 11px;text-align:left;">Bag list</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr bgcolor="#F8F8F8">
                        <th style="font-family:verdana;font-size:11;text-align:left;color:#E80000;border:solid 1px #E80000">Bag Number</th>
                    </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="/form/bagList/*">
                            <tr>
                            <xsl:variable name="css-estilo">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#F1F1F1</xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>font-family:verdana;font-size:11;border:solid 0px #F0F0F0;background-color:#FFFFFF</xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:variable>
                        <td style="{$css-estilo}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>

                        </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </table>
                    </xsl:if>                   

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>


    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="reformatDateTimeUKtoDate">
        <!-- Expected format 20-08-2010 11:11:30:000000 -->
        <!-- Expected output 20-08-2010 -->
        <xsl:param name="dateTime"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($dateTime,1,10)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="formatAcc">
        <xsl:param name="requestor"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after($requestor, ':'), ':' , ' ')"/>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is when getting the tcRef tag which contains a £. In local ie is displaying "Â£" :

[image]

Which should be the proper encoding configuration?

When trying to test it in our application, IE is displaying an error:

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

An invalid character was found in text content. Error processing resource 'http://abb.com...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://abb.com
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear exactly what's going on. What's serving the data? Do you get the same problem if the files are just local? Is it only the browser which is processing the XML?

Comment: Are you sure your files are actually using UTF-8 encoding? It's not enough to declare the encoding in the prolog...

Comment: Yes, both files xml and xslt are encoding in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the server is sending the wrong charset in the `Content-Type` header. If this is so, including the following after `<html>` in your template could help:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```